# Spring Boot: how to display corectly JSP on Browser

Tags: spring, maven, jsp, spring-boot

I am making an Spring Boot Application but when I visit http://localhost:8080 in my browser the response is showing the .jsp tags(code) instead of showing the content correctly.

My simple .jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
Hello World!
</html>
```

And it shows:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
Hello World!
```

Comment: If you're having a problem, it is highly encouraged to post a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable exmple (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without any code to reproduce the problem, we can only guess at what the issue is.

Comment: I didn't write any code because it was the default configuration. I think I should have put at least the .jsp headers. What do you think?

Comment: Where did you put the JSP file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in pom.xml the necesary dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And the content of .jsp will be shown correctly